# STL C++ isgreater template

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, stl, predicates

when sorting a vector i am using the following code

`sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), less<int>());`

compiler accepts the third argument which is also the default argument. But for sorting in descending order i see 
`greater<int>()` 
on every forum but my compiler only accepts

`sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), isgreater<int, int>);`

which works by the way.
is the template updated in c++ or is the older greater<>() in some other library?

Answer (score 2):

The template is called `std::greater`, and it is declared in the header `<functional>`, which you must include.